# Print Location of Value within a list of lists Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, enumerate

If I am given a list with a few lists within it and I want the location of each occurrence of a value or string, how might I do that given the following code:

```
testlist = [[1, 2, 3],[ 5, 3, 1],[ 2, 1, 6]]
```

for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(testlist) if x == 1]:
    print i

I would think it would print out

```
[0][0]
[2][1]
```

I don't just want to say:

> print testlist[0][0]

How might this be achieved?

Comment: I know I could simply say print testlist[1][2]. I'm speaking in terms: if the structure of testlist can change. Then print testlist[1][2] would be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [121]: testlist = [[1, 2, 3],[ 5, 3, 1],[ 2, 1, 6]]

In [122]: for i,sub in enumerate(testlist):
   .....:     for j,num in enumerate(sub):
   .....:         if num==1: print("[{}][{}]".format(i,j))
   .....:         
[0][0]
[1][2]
[2][1]
```

If you want a function that looks for any generic value:

```
def search(L, val):
    answer = []
    for i, sub in enumerate(L):
        for j,num in enumerate(sub):
            if num==val:
                answer.append([i,j])
    return answer
```

If you want a one-liner:

```
val = 1
answer = [[i,j] for i,sub in enumerate(testlist) for j,num in enumerate(sub) if num==val]
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured extracting the location of a value within a list of lists wouldn't be as easy as print testlist[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

```
ll = [[1, 2, 3],[ 5, 3, 1],[ 2, 1, 6]]

for k, el in enumerate(ll):
    for i,j in enumerate(el):
        print("row {} column {} elemen {}".format(k, i, j))

row 0 column 0 elemen 1
row 0 column 1 elemen 2
row 0 column 2 elemen 3
row 1 column 0 elemen 5
row 1 column 1 elemen 3
row 1 column 2 elemen 1
row 2 column 0 elemen 2
row 2 column 1 elemen 1
row 2 column 2 elemen 6
```